# Comparison between two binomial lotteries

Tags: probability

I've banging my head on the wall for the last two days with the problem below.

Consider two lotteries based on two distinct binomial distributions,
$B\left(n_{1},p\right)$ and $B\left(n_{2},p\right)$, with $n_{2}\geq n_{1}+1$.
Note that $p$ is the same in both.

First lottery, with $B\left(n_{1},p\right)$: you win if there are
fewer than $k_{1}$ successes.

Second lottery, with $B\left(n_{2},p\right)$: you win if there are
fewer than $k_{2}$ successes, with $k_{2}>k_{1}$.

In both lotteries, any "success" thus diminishes your chances of winning.
The second lottery admits more successes (as $k_{2}>k_{1}$), but in more trials (as $n_{2}>n_{1}$):
hence, there is an obvious trade-off between the two
lotteries.

I basically want to show that there is a unique $\hat{p}$ such that
for any $p<\hat{p}$ ($>$), the second lottery always yield higher (lower)
expected chances of winning.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Approximate solution:  If you approximate your lotteries by normal distributions, we just have to solve for $\hat p$ which makes the 2 Z-scores equal.  To be precise:  we approximate $$B(n,p) \sim N \left( np, \sqrt{np(1-p)} \right)$$ We see that we want $\hat p$ for which $$\frac {k_1-n_1 \hat p}{\sqrt{n_1 \hat p (1 - \hat p)}} = \frac {k_2-n_2 \hat p}{\sqrt{n_2 \hat p (1 - \hat p)}}$$ (where we have assumed, for simplicity, that $k_1$ and $k_2$ are both above their respective means.).  This is easily solved...trusting that everything went through without error we end up with:
$$\hat p = \frac{k_2 \sqrt{n_1} - k_1 \sqrt{n_2}}{n_2 \sqrt{n_1} - n_1 \sqrt{n_2}}$$  This will not exist for all values...in particular we need the numerator to be positive (and the whole expression to be between 0 and 1).

Comment: thanks mate, that is a good answer.

the thing is that I am working with small "n" and "k", which makes this approximation definitely less precise. However, I don't need it to be precise: I just need the existence (and uniqueness) of  $\hat{p}$. 

Do you think this solution is sufficient to argue that even with small n and k, there must be a unique such  $\hat{p}$?